# Memory placement of local variables

Tags: c++

Assuming I have two variables in my scope.

`int a, b;`

Is it safe to assume that they will be stored one after the other in the process' memory? (with a difference of `sizeof(int)`)

Comment: Quick answer, no.

Comment: They will be stored one after the other - what is not defined is which one is stored in the lower address, and what (if any) is the padding between them.

Comment: You can only use this technique on parameters (they have a defined order) of functions with certain calling conventions. That's how varargs are determined.

Comment: @engf-010 - not really , parameters may not even be in memory, they might be in registers. varargs works how the compiler / c runtime writers decided it would work for a given toolchain / flag combination

Comment: The variables may be stored in the processors registers and thus have no accessible memory location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that scope is local function scope then no, it's not safe to assume. The standard gives you no guarantees on this. (as opposed to `structs`)

Answer (score 0):

No , it is not safe to assume.
But most of times ,  they will be stored one after the other in the process' memory.

Like this :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    cout<<&a<<endl;
    cout<<&b<<endl;

    int c;
    int d;
    cout<<&c<<endl;
    cout<<&d;

}
```

Output for the following program is : 
[image]

Here , we can easily notice that these four addresses are simply four contiguous memory blocks( with a difference of sizeof(int)).

Comment: Most of the time (depending on the definition of "most" and "the time", of course) the variables will be in registers (unless you explicitly take the address, forcing them to be placed into memory somewhere, probably stack). And even if the variables are in memory, if the value happens to be in a register temporarily, strict aliasing allows compiler to just use the value in register without checking the memory. You should really qualify this answer as "assuming no optimizations, and assuming the address of variables is taken at some point."

Comment: You need to consider registers.  Compilers are allowed to use registers to represent variables.  You would see this in the assembly language listing.